# ExtJS 4, Issue in grid with selType: checkboxmodel, after first click scroll to top

Tags: grid, extjs4

I have a grid with `selType: 'checkboxmodel'` but in IE there is an issue: after clicking on grid row (selecting it) page scroll to position that first row is on top.

Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a proper anwser

```
        Ext.override(Ext.selection.CheckboxModel, {
            onRowMouseDown: function (view, record, item, index, e) {
                //view.el.focus(); - commented focus()
                var me = this,
                    checker = e.getTarget('.' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-row-checker'),
                    mode;
                if (!me.allowRightMouseSelection(e)) {
                    return;
                }
                if (me.checkOnly && !checker) {
                    return;
                }
                if (checker) {
                    mode = me.getSelectionMode();
                    if (mode !== 'SINGLE') {
                        me.setSelectionMode('SIMPLE');
                    }
                    me.selectWithEvent(record, e);
                    me.setSelectionMode(mode);
                } else {
                    me.selectWithEvent(record, e);
                }
            }
        });
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which solves root cause of the problem for all scenarious and selection models:

```
Ext.override(Ext.dom.Element, {
    focus: function (defer, dom) {
        var me = this,
            scrollTop,
            body;

        dom = dom || me.dom;
        body = (dom.ownerDocument || DOC).body || DOC.body;
        try {
            if (Number(defer)) {
                Ext.defer(me.focus, defer, me, [null, dom]);
            } else {
                if (dom.tagName != 'DIV') {
                    if (dom.offsetHeight > Ext.dom.Element.getViewHeight()) {
                        scrollTop = body.scrollTop;
                    }
                    dom.focus();
                    if (scrollTop !== undefined) {
                        body.scrollTop = scrollTop;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e) {
        }
        return me;
    }
});
```